# Moment.js - Get all mondays between a date range

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs

I have a date range that looks like this

```
let start = moment(this.absence.FromDate);
let end = moment(this.absence.ToDate);
```

The user can decide to deactivate specific week days during that date range, so I have booleans

```
monday = true;
tuesday = false;
...
```

I want to create a function that allows me to put all mondays during my date range in an array.

I've looked around on stack but I can only find help for people who need all the monday from a month for example.

Comment: I think I remember momentjs() provide a function `moment().day()` which gives you the day of the week ( a number between 0 and 6 ). You could work with that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get next Monday using [`.day(1)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/) and then loop until your date [`isBefore`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/) your `end` date adding 7 days for each iteration using [`add`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/)

Here a live sample:

```js
//let start = moment(this.absence.FromDate);
//let end = moment(this.absence.ToDate);

// Test values
let start = moment();
let end = moment().add(45 , 'd');

var arr = [];
// Get "next" monday
let tmp = start.clone().day(1);
if( tmp.isAfter(start, 'd') ){
  arr.push(tmp.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
}
while( tmp.isBefore(end) ){
  tmp.add(7, 'days');
  arr.push(tmp.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
}
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is the point of `if( tmp.isAfter(start, 'd') ){ arr.push(tmp.format('YYYY-MM-DD')); }`?

Comment: @ElliotSchep that part of code includes first Monday for some some edge cases (e.g. `start` is Sunday or Monday). Obviously is not the only way to do it, but I thought it was the simplest one.

Comment: if start date is a monday it will be missing so you'll need to use `tmp.isSameOrAfter(start, 'd')`

Comment: One suggestion of correction. In the loop While, reverse .add() and .push(). Because that adds 7 days before to push the date that been checked by the condition. So that return a date 7 days over the limit date.