# javascript momentJS falls back to js Date() while adding the days

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs

What I am trying to do is ,in fullcalendar, get the Date that match with the given dayofweek, and change the background color of them. For example, if the given day is Thursday, then find the date that is Thursday is the current month. However, the problem is momentJS falls back to js Date(), so the browser in smartphone couldn't catch any of date, so the color is not changed in the mobile device.
Here is JS code

```
                        var currentdate = new Date();
                        var date = currentdate.getDate();
                        var dd = 1
                        var mm = currentdate.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
                        var yyyy = currentdate.getFullYear();
                        var dateforcolor = [];

                        for(var j = 0; j < dowlist.length; j++)
                        {
                            dd = 1;

                            for(var i =0; i< 32; i++)
                            {
                                var dateforpush = new Date(yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd);
                                var momentdate = moment(dateforpush).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                                var day = moment(momentdate).day();




                                if(day == dowlist[j])
                                {   
                                    dateforcolor.push(momentdate);

                                }

                                dd = dd + 1;
                            }
                        }

                        for(var i = 0; i < dateforcolor.length; i++)
                        {

                            $('.fc-day[data-date="' + dateforcolor[i] + '"]').css('background', 'Bisque');
                        }



                    }
```

and this is alert from console

> moment.min.js:1 Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
>   Arguments: 
>   [0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: Invalid date, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]

Comment: The problem is, MomentJS will never give you any warning when the passed argument is a JavaScript date object, or a string in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. You can see it in action [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x8nhvpmq/4/).

Comment: The code above doesn't give the warning you mention, as 31piy correctly states. It would do if you did `var momentdate = moment(yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd);` directly. momentJS accepts strings directly - see http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/. However the string you're passing is clearly not in a format it understands. Likely you're passing something like "2018-7-1" when moment would expect "2018-07-01" - unless of course you tell it a custom format to expect - see http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: @ADyson Sorry, I edited my code, and I am really sure this makes the error

Comment: @31piy I think that while increasing variable dd, some errors occur.

Comment: @yongseung it'll be because `dd` gets to 32 - see https://jsfiddle.net/x8nhvpmq/7/ your loop uses `i` to restrict it, but since `dd` is always `i+1`, stopping when i = 31 is going one step too far. Even then, the approach is still naive. Not all months have 31 days, as I'm sure you know! You're also assuming that fullCalendar is even showing a full month in its display...there are "week" and "day" views as well. fullCalendar can tell you the limits of the current view - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/getView and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-object

Comment: @yongseung You know also...`var momentdate = moment(dateforpush).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                                var day = moment(momentdate).day();` this is redundant. Why make a moment, stringify it again, and then make another moment? It's a bit pointless. Just run `day()` directly on the first moment you create, you don't need to do format() first - that's just for displaying it.

Comment: @yongseung anyway instead of just naively looping over all days in the month and trying to match them to the dowlist, use the methods I suggested to get the current start and end dates of the view (could even be _more_ than a month!!), and then, for each day in your dowlist, work out all the occurrences of that day between the start and end dates (here's a clue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44909902/5947043 - it's done for Mondays but you can just vary the day variable instead of hard-coding it), and then just do your colour operation on those days.

Comment: @yongseung ....and don't mess about with JS Dates or formatted strings, you can do everything you need to directly in momentJS objects (especially since the start and end dates you get from the View object will already be moments), it will be much simpler.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for giving me a way much better solution!!