# Angular - create a function the takes 2 dates and a day of the week and create an array of the the dates of the same days of the week

Tags: node.js, angular, express, date

I'm building a course manager API with Angular and Nodejs express and I'm stuck trying to figure out:

I'm trying to figure out how to create a method/function that receives 2 dates, (a time frame -> 1.1.2021 - 30.1.2021) and a weekday (let's say Monday).

And returns an array of all the Mondays between the time frame.

Example:
Course start date: 1.1.2021
Course end date: 30.1.2021
Course day: Monday

And It will return: [4.1.2021,11.1.2021,18.1.2021,25.1.2021,4.1.2021] - those are the dates of all the Mondays in the time frame of 1.1.2021 - 30.1.2021

Could someone give me a hint on how to do that? I tried to use the Date range picker but got nowhere. Is there any built-in function that I can use ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEJTo.png)

Comment: You can achieve it using moment.js take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44909662/moment-js-get-all-mondays-between-a-date-range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v2.23.0/docs/eachDayOfInterval)

```js
eachDayOfInterval({start, end}).filter(z => getDay(z) === day)
```

Where `start` and `end` are normal `Date` objects, and `day` is the weekday (0-Sunday, 1-Monday, etc.)

Comment: By the way, this answer is entirely unrelated to Angular :)